# request.get() returns encoded data while scraping a web page in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a web page naukri.com as I want to scrape all job posts for particular profile on the page.

When I try to do it using requests and bs4 all I get is encoded text. Below is the screen grab of what I am getting as response and the URL I'm trying to scrape.

here is the code.

```
url = "https://www.naukri.com/financial-analyst-jobs-in-mumbai?k=financial%20analyst&l=mumbai"
response = requests.get(url)
response.encoding
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
soup
```

I am not an expert in web scraping hence any help would be highly appreciated.

[image: My Code and Output]

Thanks!

Comment: Post your code as text instead of posting it as an image.

Comment: This is HTML of the page.

Comment: Its not encoded text. Its just plain old text. What you dont know is ```path``` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `selenium` in order to get the html code of the website:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = "https://www.naukri.com/financial-analyst-jobs-in-mumbai?k=financial%20analyst&l=mumbai"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html5lib')

print(soup.prettify())

driver.close()
```

Output:

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"/>
  <link href="//static.naukimg.com" rel="dns-prefetch preconnect"/>
  <link href="//img.naukimg.com" rel="dns-prefetch preconnect"/>
  <link href="//logs.naukri.com" rel="dns-prefetch preconnect"/>
  <link href="//lg.naukri.com" rel="dns-prefetch preconnect"/>
  <link href="https://www.googletagmanager.com" rel="dns-prefetch"/>
  <base href="//www.naukri.com"/>
  <link href="./manifest.json" rel="manifest"/>
  <link as="style" href="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/c/main.f05b7bb1.min.css" rel="preload"/>
  <link as="script" href="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/main.c5fe322d.min.js" rel="preload"/>
  <script src="https://www.googletagservices.com/activeview/js/current/osd.js?cb=%2Fr20100101">
  </script>
  <script async="" src="https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/282225171957352?v=2.9.27&amp;r=stable">
  </script>
  <script defer="" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js">
  </script>
  <script async="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script async="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script defer="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-NX744H">
  </script>
  <script>
   window.ipAddress = "www.naukri.com";
        window.DEBUG = true;
        window.appId = 135;
                    var isCrawler = false;
                            var ucBrowser = false;
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
   .splScrn{ height: 100%; } .nkIcon { width: 9rem; margin: auto; position: relative; padding-top: 95px; } #circleG { width: 9rem; margin: auto } .circleG { background-color: #2DABE2; float: left; height: 14px; margin: 5px; width: 14px; animation-name: bounce_circleG; -o-animation-name: bounce_circleG; -ms-animation-name: bounce_circleG; -webkit-animation-name: bounce_circleG; -moz-animation-name: bounce_circleG; animation-duration: 1.8s; -o-animation-duration: 1.8s; -ms-animation-duration: 1.8s; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.8s; -moz-animation-duration: 1.8s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite; -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite; -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; animation-direction: normal; -o-animation-direction: normal; -ms-animation-direction: normal; -webkit-animation-direction: normal; -moz-animation-direction: normal; border-radius: 50%; -o-border-radius: 50%; -ms-border-radius: 50%; -webkit-border-radius: 50%; -moz-border-radius: 50% } #root, body, html { height: 100% } #circleG_1 { animation-delay: .45s; -o-animation-delay: .45s; -ms-animation-delay: .45s; -webkit-animation-delay: .45s; -moz-animation-delay: .45s } #circleG_2 { animation-delay: .65s; -o-animation-delay: .65s; -ms-animation-delay: .65s; -webkit-animation-delay: .65s; -moz-animation-delay: .65s } #circleG_3 { animation-delay: .85s; -o-animation-delay: .85s; -ms-animation-delay: .85s; -webkit-animation-delay: .85s; -moz-animation-delay: .85s } #circleG_4 { animation-delay: 1.05s; -o-animation-delay: 1.05s; -ms-animation-delay: 1.05s; -webkit-animation-delay: 1.05s; -moz-animation-delay: 1.05s } #circleG_5 { animation-delay: 1.25s; -o-animation-delay: 1.25s; -ms-animation-delay: 1.25s; -webkit-animation-delay: 1.25s; -moz-animation-delay: 1.25s } @keyframes bounce_circleG { 50% { width: 10px; height: 10px; margin: 7px; background-color: rgba(12, 109, 182, 0) } }
  </style>
  <script>
   bazadebezolkohpepadr="34520464"
  </script>
  <script defer="" src="https://www.naukri.com/akam/11/20ebd6a" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script async="" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/0/1/j/ub_v1.7.min.js">
  </script>
  <script async="" src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gpt/pubads_impl_2020102701.js?21068420">
  </script>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/vendors~Layout.373e6600.min.js">
  </script>
  <link href="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/c/Layout.e483f39a.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/Layout.6891c30f.min.js">
  </script>
  <link href="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/c/naukriHome~searchResult.7cb53b81.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/naukriHome~searchResult.1ca34db9.min.js">
  </script>
  <link href="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/c/searchResult.a9b795eb.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/searchResult.e26b9c67.min.js">
  </script>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/jquery.7fd1ed9d.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="application/ld+json">
   {"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"BreadcrumbList","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"item":{"@id":"https://www.naukri.com","name":"Home"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"item":{"@id":"https://www.naukri.com/jobs-in-mumbai","name":"Jobs in mumbai"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":3,"item":{"@id":"https://www.naukri.com/financial-analyst-jobs","name":"financial analyst Jobs"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":4,"item":{"name":"financial analyst Jobs In mumbai"}}]}
  </script>
  <script src="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/971665778/?random=1604293270313&amp;cv=9&amp;fst=1604293270313&amp;num=1&amp;guid=ON&amp;resp=GooglemKTybQhCsO&amp;u_h=786&amp;u_w=1397&amp;u_ah=750&amp;u_aw=1397&amp;u_cd=24&amp;u_his=2&amp;u_tz=330&amp;u_java=false&amp;u_nplug=3&amp;u_nmime=4&amp;gtm=2wgal2&amp;sendb=1&amp;ig=1&amp;data=dynx_pagetype%3Dsearchresults%3Bdynx_itemid%3D-%3Bevent%3Dgtm.js&amp;frm=0&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.naukri.com%2Ffinancial-analyst-jobs-in-mumbai%3Fk%3Dfinancial%2520analyst%26l%3Dmumbai&amp;hn=www.googleadservices.com&amp;async=1&amp;rfmt=3&amp;fmt=4">
  </script>
  <script src="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1056982488/?random=1604293270332&amp;cv=9&amp;fst=1604293270332&amp;num=1&amp;value=0&amp;label=nnLpCKy315UBENiLgfgD&amp;guid=ON&amp;resp=GooglemKTybQhCsO&amp;u_h=786&amp;u_w=1397&amp;u_ah=750&amp;u_aw=1397&amp;u_cd=24&amp;u_his=2&amp;u_tz=330&amp;u_java=false&amp;u_nplug=3&amp;u_nmime=4&amp;gtm=2wgal2&amp;sendb=1&amp;ig=1&amp;frm=0&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.naukri.com%2Ffinancial-analyst-jobs-in-mumbai%3Fk%3Dfinancial%2520analyst%26l%3Dmumbai&amp;hn=www.googleadservices.com&amp;bttype=purchase&amp;async=1&amp;rfmt=3&amp;fmt=4">
  </script>
  <script type="application/ld+json">
   {"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"ItemList","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-finance-analyst-work-from-home-eclerx-services-ltd-pune-mumbai-0-to-1-years-201020005384"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-financial-analyst-eclerx-services-ltd-navi-mumbai-mumbai-0-to-2-years-131020007548"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":3,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-join-xl-dynamics-elite-team-of-financial-analysts-interview-home-xl-dynamics-india-pvt-ltd-navi-mumbai-0-to-5-years-191020000574"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":4,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-urgent-opening-for-financial-research-analyst-mumbai-merit-group-mumbai-0-to-5-years-281020004430"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":5,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-analyst-financial-regulatory-and-risk-rangam-infotech-pvt-ltd-mumbai-0-to-1-years-271020501425"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":6,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-financial-analyst-omega-seiki-chennai-pune-delhi-ncr-mumbai-ahmedabad-bengaluru-bangalore-surat-hyderabad-secunderabad-kolkata-0-to-5-years-311020002397"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":7,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-financial-analyst-omega-seiki-chennai-pune-delhi-ncr-mumbai-ahmedabad-bengaluru-bangalore-surat-hyderabad-secunderabad-kolkata-0-to-5-years-311020002976"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":8,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-senior-analyst-finance-processes-accenture-solutions-pvt-ltd-mumbai-5-to-8-years-211020900738"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":9,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-financial-research-analyst-merit-group-limited-mumbai-5-to-10-years-301020500231"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":10,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-financial-analyst-medusind-solutions-india-pvt-ltd-mumbai-6-to-8-years-281020005897"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":11,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-financial-reporting-analyst-teamware-solutions-mumbai-1-to-4-years-281020001120"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":12,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-financial-analyst-associate-syndicated-loan-operations-night-shift-globeop-financial-services-technologies-india-private-limited-navi-mumbai-mumbai-1-to-6-years-281020000215"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":13,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-analyst-finance-processes-accenture-solutions-pvt-ltd-mumbai-3-to-5-years-211020900892"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":14,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-analyst-finance-processes-accenture-solutions-pvt-ltd-mumbai-3-to-5-years-211020900878"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":15,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-mba-bba-b-com-ba-freshers-for-financial-analyst-profile-in-mumbai-m-s-heidrick-resources-pune-navi-mumbai-0-to-4-years-150620001472"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":16,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-financial-research-analyst-saaki-argus-and-averil-consulting-mumbai-2-to-5-years-291020602013"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":17,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-financial-research-analyst-saaki-argus-and-averil-consulting-mumbai-2-to-5-years-291020002011"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":18,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-kick-start-your-career-as-financial-analyst-this-november-dont-miss-m-s-heidrick-resources-pune-navi-mumbai-0-to-3-years-291020000221"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":19,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-financial-analyst-eclerx-mumbai-pune-prior-hr-services-pune-mumbai-0-to-3-years-291020006228"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":20,"url":"https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-finance-analyst-kande-technologies-pune-mumbai-hyderabad-secunderabad-0-to-1-years-090620501282"}],"numberOfItems":20}
  </script>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/vendors~filters.d6d4a648.min.js">
  </script>
  <link href="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/c/filters.6f4f4353.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/filters.835b0b0d.min.js">
  </script>
  <link href="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/c/listing.7b945cb6.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/listing.44ca2115.min.js">
  </script>
  <script class="dfpScript">
   googletag.cmd.push(function(){
            googletag.destroySlots();
            googletag.defineSlot('/1268732/Naukri_Display/naukri_srp_web_top_300x250', [[250,250],[300,250],[200,200],[180,150]], 'div-gpt-ad-1529415230769-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
            googletag.defineSlot('/1268732/Naukri_Display/naukri_srp_web_middle_300x250_sticky', [[250,250],[200,200],[300,300],[300,250],[180,150]], 'div-gpt-ad-1529415230769-1').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.enableServices();
        });
  </script>
  <link href="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/c/registration.daf5fd91.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/registration.24fffc83.min.js">
  </script>
  <link href="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/c/featured-companies.cb3914cb.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/featured-companies.9d313c5b.min.js">
  </script>
  <link href="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/c/ffRight.631ab153.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/ffRight.ab43570c.min.js">
  </script>
  <link as="script" href="https://adservice.google.co.in/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.naukri.com" rel="preload"/>
  <script src="https://adservice.google.co.in/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.naukri.com" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <link as="script" href="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.naukri.com" rel="preload"/>
  <script src="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.naukri.com" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <link href="https://eb56c7871ba1f40ba50b16c00f1938a7.safeframe.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-37/html/container.html" rel="prefetch"/>
  <link href="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/c/jobTuple.21a185cf.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/jobTuple.b5964b9b.min.js">
  </script>
  <link href="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/c/bellyFilters.60f996ec.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/bellyFilters.7f819837.min.js">
  </script>
  <link href="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/c/pagination.09eae69e.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/pagination.1f385dae.min.js">
  </script>
  <link href="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/c/e-learning.644f16aa.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/e-learning.0591ad78.min.js">
  </script>
  <link href="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/c/fatFooter.de7ff8d8.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/fatFooter.9cf4f997.min.js">
  </script>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/dropdown.60afc5b6.min.js">
  </script>
  <link href="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/c/tagsAndSkills.d010ce09.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="//static.naukimg.com/s/7/109/j/tagsAndSkills.addc218a.min.js">
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <noscript>
   <iframe height="0" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-NX744H" style="display:none;visibility:hidden" width="0">
   </iframe>
  </noscript>
  <div id="root">
   <div class="headGNBWrap">
    <div class="headGNB cloneCont wrap" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
     <a class="fl nLogo" href="https://www.naukri.com" itemprop="url">
      <img data-ga-track="Company Logo|Company Logo" itemprop="logo" src="https://static.naukimg.com/s/4/100/i/naukri_Logo.png"/>
     </a>
     <ul class="midSec menu">
      <li class="mActive">
       <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Jobs|Jobs Icon" href="https://www.naukri.com/browse-jobs" target="_blank" title="Search Jobs">
        <span class="topIcon jobs">
        </span>
        <div class="mTxt">
         Jobs
        </div>
       </a>
       <div class="subMenu c2">
        <ul class="group">
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Jobs|Search Jobs" href="https://www.naukri.com" target="_blank" title="Search Jobs">
           Search Jobs
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a class="target_advanceSeachLayer" data-domain="https://www.naukri.com/" data-ga-track="Main Navigation Jobs|Advanced Search" href="https://www.naukri.com/advanced-search" target="_blank" title="Advanced Search">
           Advanced Search
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Jobs|Create Free Job Alert" href="https://www.naukri.com/free-job-alerts" target="_blank" title="Create Free Job Alert">
           Create Free Job Alert
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Jobs|Register Now" href="https://www.naukri.com/account/createaccount?othersrcp=16201&amp;err=1" target="_blank" title="Register Now">
           Register Now
          </a>
         </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="group">
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Jobs|Jobs by Location" href="https://www.naukri.com/jobs-by-location" target="_blank" title="Jobs by Location">
           Jobs by Location
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Jobs|Jobs by Skill" href="https://www.naukri.com/top-skill-jobs" target="_blank" title="Jobs by Skill">
           Jobs by Skill
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Jobs|Jobs by Designation" href="https://www.naukri.com/top-jobs-by-designations" target="_blank" title="Jobs by Designation">
           Jobs by Designation
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Jobs|Jobs by Company" href="https://www.naukri.com/top-company-jobs" target="_blank" title="Jobs by Company">
           Jobs by Company
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Jobs|Jobs by Category" href="https://www.naukri.com/jobs-by-category" target="_blank" title="Jobs by Category">
           Jobs by Category
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Jobs|Browse All Jobs" href="https://www.naukri.com/browse-jobs" target="_blank" title="Browse All Jobs">
           Browse All Jobs
          </a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Recruiters|Recruiters Icon" href="https://www.naukri.com/recruiters" target="_blank" title="Search Recruiters">
        <span class="topIcon jobs Recr">
        </span>
        <div class="mTxt">
         Recruiters
        </div>
       </a>
       <div class="subMenu">
        <ul>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Recruiters|Browse all" href="https://www.naukri.com/recruiters/browse-all-recruiters" target="_blank" title="Browse All Recruiters">
           Browse All Recruiters
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Recruiters|Recruiter Connection" href="https://resume.naukri.com/contact-recruiters-hr?fftid=GNB_RC" target="_blank" title="Recruiter Connection">
           Recruiter Connection
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Recruiters|Goto Naukri Recruiter" href="https://naukrirecruiter.naukri.com?src=128" target="_blank" title="Go to NaukriRecruiter">
           Go to NaukriRecruiter
          </a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Companies|Companies Icon" href="https://www.naukri.com/top-company-jobs" target="_blank" title="Jobs Posted By Top Companies">
        <span class="topIcon jobs Comp">
        </span>
        <div class="mTxt">
         Companies
        </div>
       </a>
       <div class="subMenu">
        <ul>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Companies|Browse All Companies" href="https://www.naukri.com/top-company-jobs" target="_blank" title="Browse All Companies">
           Browse All Companies
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Companies|About Companies" href="https://www.ambitionbox.com/companies?utm_source=naukri&amp;utm_medium=gnb" rel="noindex nofollow" target="_blank" title="About Companies">
           About Companies
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Companies|Interview Questions" href="https://www.ambitionbox.com/interviews?utm_source=naukri&amp;utm_medium=gnb" target="_blank" title="Interview Questions">
           Interview Questions
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Companies|Write Company Review" href="https://www.ambitionbox.com/contribute/company-review?utm_source=naukri&amp;utm_medium=gnb" rel="noindex nofollow" target="_blank" title="Write Company Review">
           Write Company Review
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Companies|Share Interview Questions" href="https://www.ambitionbox.com/contribute/interview-story?utm_source=naukri&amp;utm_medium=gnb" target="_blank" title="Write Interview Advice">
           Write Interview Advice
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Companies|Company Reviews" href="https://www.ambitionbox.com/reviews?utm_source=naukri&amp;utm_medium=gnb" target="_blank" title="Company Reviews">
           Company Reviews
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Companies|Company Salaries" href="https://www.ambitionbox.com/salaries?utm_source=naukri&amp;utm_medium=desktop&amp;utm_campaign=gnb" target="_blank" title="Company Salaries">
           Company Salaries
          </a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Insights|Insights Icon" href="https://insights.naukri.com" target="_blank">
        <span class="topIcon jobs Insights">
        </span>
        <div class="mTxt">
         Tools
        </div>
       </a>
       <div class="subMenu">
        <ul>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Insights|Salary Trends" href="https://insights.naukri.com" target="_blank" title="Salary Trends">
           Salary Trends (β)
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Insights|Career Navigator" href="https://insights.naukri.com/careernavigator" target="_blank" title="Career Navigator">
           Career Navigator (β)
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Insights|People Flow" href="https://insights.naukri.com/peopleflow" target="_blank" title="People Flow">
           People Flow (β)
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Insights|Talent Migration" href="http://insights.naukri.com/talentmigration" target="_blank" title="Talent Migration">
           Talent Migration (β)
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Insights|Salary Prediction" href="http://insights.naukri.com/salarypredictor" target="_blank" title="Salary Prediction">
           Salary Prediction (β)
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Insights|Find my Alumni" href="http://insights.naukri.com/myalumni/" target="_blank" title="Find my Alumni">
           Find my Alumni (β)
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Insights|careerTrajectory" href="http://insights.naukri.com/naukri-trajectory/" target="_blank" title="Career Trajectory">
           Career Trajectory (β)
          </a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a data-ga-track="Main Navigation Insights|Boomerang" href="http://insights.naukri.com/boomerang" target="_blank" title="Boomerang">
           Boomerang (β)
          </a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
      ...
  <iframe id="google_osd_static_frame_7179478265707" name="google_osd_static_frame" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;">
  </iframe>
  <iframe height="0" src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/sodar/sodar2/219/runner.html" style="display: none;" width="0">
  </iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok...But you have to install `selenium` and a `chromedriver` in order to run this script.

Comment: Selenium is slow once you have everything installed. It is also very resource intensive and not the most efficient way to extract the HTML (or any data for that matter) from a web page

Comment: But the same result can't be achieved using `requests`. That's the sole reason behind why I used `selenium`.

Comment: much thanks Sushil...it solved my problem..marked it as solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.text` property of the `requests` response to load the data into a bs4 object using the `requests` library. This is the fastest way to load the data without needing to configure or wait for other libraries to load the page

Example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

You now have a bs4 object to do your parsing.

Comment: this is what I have been doing but still I get the same response...don't get html code of the web page.